How to get Microsoft Azure hosting a Static Web App to recognize update to codebase in GitHub?
I have a static web app that is hosted on Microsoft Azure.
I just updated some of the code in GitHub that Microsoft Azure
uses for the web app.
When I visit my website, none of the code changes have taken effect.
Do I need to trigger Azure to re-read GitHub to get the updates, or is this somehow supposed to be automatic?
Thanks!

If possible, share your github workflow?


Do I need to trigger Azure to re-read GitHub to get the updates, or is this somehow supposed to be automatic?

No, the deployment process through GitHub for Azure Static Web app is to be Automatic when changes are pushed to the repository. No need to manually trigger Azure to re-read GitHub to get the updates.
Azure Static Web Apps uses GitHub Actions Workflow file to deploy changes from GitHub repository.
The workflow file will be automatically created when the Static Web App connected to GitHub and Creates Run job as shown below.

Make Sure that the correct branch is specified in the below section. It Creates New Run Job when there is Push to master branch.
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

Below section helps workflow should trigger for pull requests targeting the master branch.
pull_request:
  types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
  branches:
    - master

By using the below condition, the build and deploy job will run on any push to branch or when a pull request is created or updated as long as it is not closed.
if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')

By using above Workflow code, I can Automatically trigger the Code changes to Azure Static Web app.
Below is my Complete GitHub/Workflow File:
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_THANKFUL_BUSH_<Key> }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "./BlazorApp38" 
          api_location: "Api" 
          output_location: "wwwroot" 
  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_THANKFUL_BUSH_<Key> }}
          action: "close"

You can also manually trigger changes to Azure Static Web   follow below steps.
Go to Actions tab -> Select the Latest Workflow run -> Re-run all jobs -> Re-run jobs.




Hi Azure, could you explain how to get to the "Actions Tab" from the default page Azure puts you into when you login? I do not know Azure very well. When I login, it says "Azure Services" at the top, and below I see options for: Create a Resource, Azure Deployment, Monitor, Bastions, All Resources, Reservations, Help + Support, App Services, Azure Spring Apps, and then a right arrow with "More Services." Thanks so much!

Sorry Asleasha - got your name wrong! Apologize!

@user1104028 I didn't understand your query, Can you please explain more clearly.

Can you specify the complete path to get to the Actions Tab to invoke a deployment? If you deploy via the Actions Tab, do you still need a .yaml file?

@user1104028 It is GitHub repository Action tab.
